# Linear matrix inequality

Tags: linear-matrix-inequality

I have the following LMI (linear matrix inequality):
$F^TP+PF\leq 0$ where $P$ is a positive definite matrix.
if I have the following condition $Q\leq P$, $Q$ is a positive definite matrix.
is it right to write the LMI as $F^TQ+QF\leq 0$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $Q \leq P$ ? You have a norm on $M_n$ that allows you to say so ?

Comment: By $\geq$, do you mean $succeq$, the ordering of matrices with respect to the cone of positive semidefinite matrices?  Or, do you mean elementwise inequality?

Comment: $Q-P \leq 0$ is negative definite all the eigenvalue of $Q-P$ are negatives

Comment: The same question on MathOverflow: [linear matrix inequiality](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310932). I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice on cross-posting. Of course, other posts tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) on meta might be worth having a look.

Comment: I answered with a counterexample at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310932/linear-matrix-inequality